# How to pass the same parameter multiple times in CoreData iOS predicate builder?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have a `UITableView` with a `UISearchbar` that let me filter the data based on the `search text` from the `UISearchbar`.

The `CoreData` table contains `3 attributes`

```
name, notes, date
```

I want to search the three columns for any occurrence based on the `User` search text.

So I tried this on:

```
let searchText = searchText.lowercased()
let query = "name contains[cd] %@ OR notes contains[cd] %@ OR date contains[cd] %@"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: query, searchText, searchText, searchText)
```

Is there any way to pass the same parameter *(`searchText`)* one time?

Something like `Java` string formatter:

```
let query = "name contains[cd] %1$@ OR notes contains[cd] %1$@ OR date contains[cd] %1$@"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: query, searchText)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *substitution variables*:

```
let searchText = searchText.lowercased()
let template = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] $SRCH OR notes contains[cd] $SRCH OR date contains[cd] $SRCH")
let subVars = ["SRCH": searchText]
let predicate = template.withSubstitutionVariables(subVars)
```

See "Creating Predicates using Predicate Templates" in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-CJBDBHCB).

Comment: is it safe for `sql injection` ?

Comment: I think so.  The parsing of the format string is mainly done in the initial creation of the template, so is subject to the same checks as a normal predicate format string.  The substitution process will enclose strings in quotes which should prevent sql injection.